# How to get scrollMaxX, and scrollMaxY in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am writing an extension to get the scrollMaxX and scrollMaxY values for a page but as per the documentation at w3schools.com it seems that, this property is not supported by the chrome browser. It is working for me in firefox.  Please suggest how can i get these values for chrome browser.

Comment: Many Many Thanks to you Chris!  You made my day , this solution  is just rocking.....

Answer (score -1):

> `document.body.scrollHeight` Is described as - The Element.scrollHeight read-only property is a measurement of the
>   height of an element's content, including content not visible on the
>   screen due to overflow.
>
> The scrollHeight value is equal to the minimum height the element
>   would require in order to fit all the content in the viewport without
>   using a vertical scrollbar.

You can take away the inner height of the viewport:

> `document.body.scrollHeight` Height (in pixels) of the browser window viewport including, if rendered, the
>   horizontal scrollbar.

So your answer would be

```
document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score -3):

this work for me in IE, Chrome and Firefox:

```
function getScrollMaxY(){
    return ( 'scrollMaxY' in window ) ? window.scrollMaxY : (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
}
```